# issues parsing html in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

running into this error whilst making a script to pull headlines from a url. 
(edit; should add i have ensured python 3 and request, lxml, and beautiful soup modules are all installed)

> UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently. The code that caused this warning is on line 9 of the file news.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml



url = 'http://www.news.google.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)



for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):
    print()`
```

Comment: Thats a warning — not an error. It's also probably been discussed on here many times before.

Answer (score 0):

Please do `pip install lxml` in your terminal/cmd to resolve this issue.

You can either use `lxml` or `html.parser` or *other* see the difference [HERE](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

Instead of the `'lxml'` you can choose one from the docs that suits your needs.

Example (*if we were to use `html5lib`)*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: i have ensured in terminal lxml is installed.

Comment: Updated answer, that should do it.

Comment: thank you! im to new to have my thumbs up show thank you!

Comment: If my answer is the correct one (please Tick it, next to the arrow up) to choose the answer button making sure other people find it useful too, thank you.

Comment: sorry mate i did but im to new to stack :(Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Great, take care, I hope you will find StackOverflow useful as many other's have.  Very speedy replies and fully accurate.

Comment: i have just need to stop lurking thank you again